# Create Item in Document Library thru REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, sharepoint-rest-api, custom-content-type

Is there a way to create an item inside a list library? Or perhaps convert a folder/file into a custom Content Type? I have added an item using custom content type thru the "New" menu (named "g1q" on screenshot)

[image]

Now I want to replicate this by adding it thru REST API, at first I created a folder "abc" and tried to change the content type via REST, checking on the Content Type ID I have successfully changed it, but in the page it is still a folder. Tried converting the file "g1q test.png" and still got the same result.

Is there a way around this?